# How to get revision number from Android build from Azure DevOps and display it in Android app?

Tags: android, azure-devops

I have an Android application and configured Azure DevOps pipelines to build and publish apks.

When I am downloading the build, I want to display the build number `$(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)` in the debug menu in my application via `BuildConfig.AZURE_BUILD_NUMBER`

I can't find any examples of this issue. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: use this https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.GetRevision

Answer (score 0):

We can install the extension [Mobile App Tasks for iOS and Android](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-473885.motz-mobile-buildtasks) and use the task "Bump Version" (for Andriod and iOS) to change app's version name and code at build time.